# Get Remove ME from string C Challenge

Tags: c, string

Need to remove the padding characters from this string i.e `"REMOVEMEHOW"` and its needs to be removed by chopping and not matching the case and I am trying to chop a header section of buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <windows.h> 

int main () 
{     
    char buffer[200]="REMOVEMEHOW**THIS IS THE REST OF THE STRING THAT IS FINE***REMOVEMEHOW";    

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [strstr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) from the string.h library. (The link I give here is for C++, but C has the same function.)

Answer (score 1):

If you know, how many (`N_front`, `N_back`) chars to remove:

Move everything after the `N_front`th char forward by `N_front` and set the terminating null byte.

```
memmove (buffer, buffer + N_front, 200 - N_front);
buffer[strlen(buffer) - N_back] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks that skips the spaces fine at beginning however only seems to display a few bytes of text I have included a printout above of the buffer i am using it seeems to fail after the MFI part any ideas guys?

Comment: @user1539199 If your buffer contains any `'\0'` characters other than the one at the end, then `strlen` will not give you the value that you expect.  Print out the value of `strlen` both before and after the `memmove` call and make sure that they match what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* strrmv(char *text, char *removeword){
    char *p=text;
    int rlen;
    rlen = strlen(removeword);
    while(NULL!=(p=strstr(p, removeword))){
        memmove(p, p+rlen, strlen(p+rlen)+1);
    }
    return text;
}

int main(){
    char buffer[200]="REMOVEMEHOW**THIS IS THE REST OF THE STRING THAT IS FINE***REMOVEMEHOW";

    printf("\"%s\"", strrmv(buffer, "REMOVEMEHOW"));
    return 0; 
}
```